# How to pass variable from child to parent graph node in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a view which collects inputs from user and creates new object with route "main/new" and one of the fields should be Date. I used DatePickerDialog on route "main/new/calendar" which after clicking Ok button should save Date to UiState of it's parent (path "main/new") 
[image]

However after clicking Ok button Date does not change. 
[image]
I was trying to update it via function in class MyViewModel using state flows

```
fun updateState(fieldId: Int, fieldValue: Any?){ //same usage as edit habit
    _habitUiState.update { currentState ->
        when(fieldId){
            2 -> {
                currentState.copy(name = fieldValue.toString())
            }

            3 -> {
                var actualValue = fieldValue
                actualValue = if (fieldValue == null){
                    ""
                } else{
                    actualValue.toString()
                }
                currentState.copy(description = actualValue)
            }

            5 -> {
                currentState.copy(nextOccurring = fieldValue as Date?)
            }

            6 -> {
                currentState.copy(intervalDays = fieldValue as Int?)
            }

            else -> {
                Log.d("HabitUiStateError","FieldId: ${fieldId}, FieldValue: {$fieldValue}")
                currentState.copy()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like so:

```
DatePickerDialog(
    onDismissRequest = {navController.popBackStack()},
    confirmButton = {
        Button(onClick = {
            var longDate = 1L
            if (datePickerState.selectedDateMillis != null){
                longDate = datePickerState.selectedDateMillis!!
            }
            val date = Date(longDate)
            myViewModel.updateState(5, date)
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
 ...
```

Other cases work because they are in parent function.
Is there a way to update parent UI without using Shared View Model?